# Maxscale keep connections that are killed by the application

Tags: mysql, load-balancing, hikaricp, mysql-5.7, maxscale

We are trying to use maxscale for DB load balancing (MySQL 5.7).

We are using Hikari for application connection pool.
We would like that the Hikari will manage the connection pooling and maxscale will follow the connections from Hikari's side.

For the test we only have the master connected to maxscale.
Both Hikari and the application are set to 20 max connections.

On max scale we use the following configuration:
Host configuration
persistpoolmax=0
persistmaxtime=60

service configuration
max_connections=20
We also commented out the connection_timeout on the service section.

What we see, is when we stop the applications, the connections remain open on maxscale and when we restart the application, if fails to connect on max-connections exceeded.

What are we doing wrong?

Comment: Did you define `max_connections` only for MaxScale or also for the database?

Comment: Database max_connections is much higher then the maxscale (600 vs 20)